# Сниффер C++

Tags: ip, tcp, udp, сниффер, c++

Есть сниффер , ловит пакеты записывает заголовочную информацию в файл.
Препод требует допустим если udp пакет записывал еще порты , icmp - тип icmp и код icmp(все это в структуре заголовка есть). Проблема в том что в Udp src_port все время пишит "69" также в icmp type "69" в tcp src_port "128". Подскажите где  косячу :(?

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#include <fstream>
using std::fstream;
#include "WinSock2.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <process.h>
#define MAX_PACKET_SIZE    30000
#define SIO_RCVALL         0x98000001
FILE* f,*f2;
char baf[20];
// Буфер для приёма данных
char Buf[MAX_PACKET_SIZE],Buf2[MAX_PACKET_SIZE]; // 64 Kb
typedef struct TCPHeader
{
unsigned short  src_port;   // Порт отправителя
unsigned short  dst_port;   // Порт получателя 
unsigned int    seq_n;      // Номер очереди
unsigned int    ack_n;      // Номер подтверждения
unsigned char   offset;     // Смещение данных (4 бита) 
                // + Зарезервировано (4 бита)
unsigned char   flags;      // Зарезервировано (2 бита) 
                // + Флаги (6 бит)
unsigned short  win;        // Размер окна
unsigned short  crc;        // Контрольная сумма заголовка
unsigned short  padding;    // Дополнение до 20 байт
}
TCPHeader;

typedef struct ICMPHeader 
{
unsigned char   type;           // тип ICMP- пакета
unsigned char   code;           // код ICMP- пакета 
unsigned short  crc ;           // контрольная сумма 
union {
struct { unsigned char  uc1, uc2, uc3, uc4; } s_uc;
struct { unsigned short us1, us2; } s_us;
unsigned long s_ul;
} s_icmp;               // зависит от типа
}ICMPHeader;

typedef struct IPHeader {
  UCHAR   iph_verlen;   // версия и длина заголовка
  UCHAR   iph_tos;      // тип сервиса
  USHORT  iph_length;   // длина всего пакета
  USHORT  iph_id;       // Идентификация
  USHORT  iph_offset;   // флаги и смещения
  UCHAR   iph_ttl;      // время жизни пакета
  UCHAR   iph_protocol; // протокол
  USHORT  iph_xsum;     // контрольная сумма
  ULONG   iph_src;      // IP-адрес отправителя
  ULONG   iph_dest;     // IP-адрес назначения
} IPHeader;
typedef struct UDPHeader
{
unsigned short   src_port ; // номер порта отправителя 
unsigned short   dst_port ; // номер порта получателя 
unsigned short   length;    // длина датаграммы 
unsigned short   crc;       // контрольная сумма заголовка
}UDPHeader; 
char src[10];
char dest[10];
char ds[15];
unsigned short lowbyte;
unsigned short hibyte;
unsigned short dunno;
unsigned short dunno1;
unsigned short id,summa,flags;
///////////////////
        WSADATA     wsadata;   // Инициализация WinSock.
  SOCKET      s;         // Cлущающий сокет.
  char        name[128]; // Имя хоста (компьютера).
  HOSTENT*    phe;       // Информация о хосте.
  SOCKADDR_IN sa;        // Адрес хоста
  SOCKADDR_IN sa22;
  IN_ADDR sa1;
  IN_ADDR sa2;
  unsigned long        flag = 1; 
  //////////////////

namespace Н {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Threading;

/// <summary>
/// Сводка для Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:

System::Void DoWork()
{
             while( !_kbhit() )
  {
    int count=0;
    ZeroMemory(Buf,MAX_PACKET_SIZE);
    count = recv( s, Buf, sizeof(Buf), 0 );//buf[count]
IPHeader* hdr1 = (IPHeader *)Buf;
UDPHeader* hdr2=(UDPHeader *)Buf;
TCPHeader* hdr3=(TCPHeader *)Buf;
ICMPHeader* hdr4=(ICMPHeader *)Buf;
sa2.s_addr = hdr1->iph_dest;// тут просто ловит нужные айпи и сохраняет переданные данные
sa3.s_addr = hdr1->iph_src;
if((sa2.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3==71)&&(sa2.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4==84)&&(sa3.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3==1)&&(sa3.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4==106))
{
    f2 = fopen("C:\\test2.txt","a");
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
     {
        fprintf(f2, "%c", Buf[i]);
     }
    fclose(f2);
}
    //тут все происходит************************************************
// обработка IP-пакета*******************************************
if( count >= sizeof(IPHeader) )
{
  IPHeader* hdr = (IPHeader *)Buf;
  //Начинаем разбор пакета...
id=hdr->iph_id;
itoa(id,baf,10);
f = fopen("C:\\test.txt","a");
strcpy(src,"ПакетID: ");
//CharToOem(src,dest);
//printf(dest);

fwrite(src,1,strlen(src),f);
fwrite(baf,1,strlen(baf),f);
// Преобразуем в понятный вид адрес отправителя.
fwrite(" From ",1,6,f);
sa1.s_addr = hdr->iph_src;
//printf(inet_ntoa(sa1));
fwrite(inet_ntoa(sa1),1,strlen(inet_ntoa(sa1)),f);

// Преобразуем в понятный вид адрес получателя.
//printf(" To ");
fwrite(" To ",1,5,f);
sa1.s_addr = hdr->iph_dest;
//printf(inet_ntoa(sa1));
fwrite(inet_ntoa(sa1),1,strlen(inet_ntoa(sa1)),f);

// Вычисляем протокол. 
fwrite(" Protocol: ",1,12,f);
if(hdr->iph_protocol == IPPROTO_TCP)
    {
//unsigned short    src_port;   // Порт отправителя
//unsigned short    dst_port;   // Порт получателя 
//unsigned int  seq_n;      // Номер очереди
//unsigned int  ack_n;      // Номер подтверждения

        //TCPHeader* hdr3 = (TCPHeader *)Buf;
        fwrite("TCP ",1,5,f);
        hdr3->src_port;         // Всевремя "128" как TTL
        hdr3->dst_port;
        hdr3->seq_n;
        hdr3->ack_n;
        char c111[]=" src_port :";
            //char newL[]="\r\n";
            fwrite(c111,1,sizeof(c111),f);
            dunno1=(hdr3->src_port);
            itoa(dunno,baf,10);
            fwrite(baf,1,strlen(baf),f);

            char c122[]=" port_dst :";
            //char newL[]="\r\n";
            fwrite(c122,1,sizeof(c122),f);
            dunno1=(hdr3->dst_port);
            itoa(dunno1,baf,10);
            fwrite(baf,1,strlen(baf),f);

            char c1222[]=" seq_n :";
            //char newL[]="\r\n";
            fwrite(c1222,1,sizeof(c1222),f);
            dunno1=(hdr3->seq_n);
            itoa(dunno1,baf,10);
            fwrite(baf,1,strlen(baf),f);

            char c12222[]=" ack_n :";
            //char newL[]="\r\n";
            fwrite(c12222,1,sizeof(c12222),f);
            dunno1=(hdr3->ack_n);
            itoa(dunno1,baf,10);
            fwrite(baf,1,strlen(baf),f);
    }
if(hdr->iph_protocol == IPPROTO_UDP)
    {
        fwrite("UDP ",1,5,f);
            hdr2->src_port; // Всевремя "69"
            hdr2->dst_port;

            char c1[]=" src_port :";
            //char newL[]="\r\n";
            fwrite(c1,1,sizeof(c1),f);
            dunno=(hdr2->src_port);
            itoa(dunno,baf,10);
            fwrite(baf,1,strlen(baf),f);

            char c2[]=" dst_port :";
            //char newL[]="\r\n";
            fwrite(c2,1,sizeof(c2),f);
            dunno=(hdr2->dst_port);
            itoa(dunno,baf,10);
            fwrite(baf,1,strlen(baf),f);
    }
if(hdr->iph_protocol == IPPROTO_IP) fwrite("IP ",1,4,f);
if(hdr->iph_protocol == IPPROTO_ICMP)
    {
        ICMPHeader* hdr4 = (ICMPHeader *)Buf;
        fwrite("ICMP ",1,6,f);

        char c11[]=" ICMP_type :";
            //char newL[]="\r\n";
            fwrite(c11,1,sizeof(c11),f);
            dunno=(hdr4->type);   //Всевремя "69"
            itoa(dunno,baf,10);
            fwrite(baf,1,strlen(baf),f);

            char c12[]=" ICMP_code :";
            //char newL[]="\r\n";
            fwrite(c12,1,sizeof(c12),f);
            dunno=(hdr4->code);
            itoa(dunno,baf,10);
            fwrite(baf,1,strlen(baf),f);
        //unsigned char   type;         // тип ICMP- пакета
        //unsigned char   code;         // код ICMP- пакета 
    }

// Вычисляем размер. Так как в сети принят прямой порядок
// байтов, а не обратный, то прийдётся поменять байты местами.
fwrite(" Size: ",1,7,f);
lowbyte = hdr->iph_length>>8;
hibyte = hdr->iph_length<<8;
hibyte = hibyte + lowbyte;
itoa(hibyte,baf,10);
fwrite(baf,1,strlen(baf),f);
char c[]=" TTL :";
char newL[]="\r\n";
// Вычисляем время жизни пакета.
fwrite(c,1,sizeof(c),f);

dunno=(hdr->iph_ttl);
itoa(dunno,baf,10);
fwrite(baf,1,strlen(baf),f);

char sum[]=" CRC: ";
int summa=hdr->iph_xsum;
fwrite(sum,1,strlen(sum),f);
itoa(summa,baf,10);
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        if(baf[i]=='\0')                //HEX
        break;
        fprintf(f, "%x", baf[i]);
    }
hdr2->src_port; //ports===========================================
hdr2->dst_port;

//fwrite(baf,1,strlen(baf),f);
    flags=hdr->iph_offset;
    int gg=hdr->iph_offset;
fwrite(newL,1,2,f);

fclose(f);
}
  }

 ....
   ....
 ....
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

t1= gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(this,     &Form1::DoWork));
  // инициализация
  WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsadata);
  s = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP ); 
         }
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender,                   System::EventArgs^  e) 
         {
gethostname(name, sizeof(name));
phe = gethostbyname( name );
ZeroMemory( &sa, sizeof(sa) );
sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
sa.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct in_addr *)phe->h_addr_list[0])->s_addr;
bind(s, (SOCKADDR *)&sa, sizeof(SOCKADDR));

  // Включение promiscuous mode.
  ioctlsocket(s, SIO_RCVALL, &flag);
  t1->Start();
  button1->Enabled=false;
             }
    private: System::Void Form1_FormClosing(System::Object^  sender,     System::Windows::Forms::FormClosingEventArgs^  e) 
         {
             t1->Abort();
         }
};
}
```

Comment: Вы серьёзно считаете, чтобы кому-то захочется перелопатить 300 строк кода, вперемешку фронтэнд и бекэнд, на ужасном C++/CLI, чтобы отловить вашу ошибку? А почему **вы** сами на запустите отладчик и не выясните, какая переменная имеет не то значение, которое вы ожидаете?

Если хотите, чтобы вам помогли, локализуйте проблему самостоятельно.